# How to change 'quick-reply' buttons in Mail notifications on macOS?

Tags: macos, mail.app, high-sierra

I wonder whether instead of 'Reply' and 'Close' I can have other options like 'Trash' or 'Archive' or 'Mark as Read' in notifications coming from the Mail app on macOS.