# Customize Notification Alerts/Badges

Tags: mail.app, notifications, big-sur

Is it possible to customize the alerts or badges (either will be okay) for the Mail application so that it displays **Delete** upon a mouse-over instead of **Options** --> **Delete**? I receive a lot of mails daily which I need to delete etc and it will be very handy to have such a simple feature. I am using MacOS Big Sur on MacBook Air M1.

[Related Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408288/customize-slack-notifications-banner-alerts).

Comment: I don't think there's an exposed API to make those changes.  I won't add this as an answer as I'm not 100% sure and don't want to mislead you.

Comment: It's probably even a duplicate of the question you link to, unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an option for this currently.

Comment: @fsb I would be fine with your comment as an answer, we could close one of the the Q as a duplicate then until better news come along.

Comment: Thanks @nohillside, I'll add the answer.  I also found [this similar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/351839/88313) question that can also be closed as a dup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple would need to make a way for people to change the text or functionality of these notifications.

As of this writing, Apple doesn't expose to developers or users a way to customize these alert buttons.

You can [contact Apple by completing this feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html) and telling them you want this ability.